# Setting .css() Multiple Properties not working

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to zoom in to portion of an image  by changing the div background image property. I am not sure if this is the proper way but so far it works! the only problem is passing the Multiple Properties through .css(). the properties working when I call them separately but not not together!  Can you please let me know why this code is not working?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".zoom").click(function () {
        $('.gal').css({
            background-size: "200% 200%",
            background-position: "center"
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any better idea to create a Google Map style image zoom in?
Thansk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$('.gal').css({
  background-size: "200% 200%",
  background-position : "center"
});
```

to the DOM property notation :

```
$('.gal').css({
  backgroundSize: "200% 200%",
  backgroundPosition : "center"
});
```

or add quotes around the CSS property names :

```
$('.gal').css({
  'background-size': "200% 200%",
  'background-position' : "center"
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) :

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css({'background-color': '#ffe',
>   'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'}) and .css({backgroundColor: '#ffe',
>   borderLeft: '5px solid #ccc'}). Notice that with the DOM notation,
>   quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS
>   notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.